# Template universal reference in c++

Tags: c++, templates, static-assert, forwarding-reference

Why is `U` not deduced as `int&&`?

```
#include <type_traits>
template<class T>
class Test
{
  public:
  template<class U>
  Test<T>(U && obj)
  {
    static_assert(false == std::is_rvalue_reference<U>::value, "Rvalues not accepted");
  }
};


int main()
{
   Test<int>{5};   // I expected this not to compile

   int x;
   Test<int>{x};
}
```

Comment: The same scenario in the question marked by Sombrero Chicken but i don't understand why should i put U&& to be deductible.